# 2 different listed elements without the same members in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums

I just want to create data structure which I can use with syntax prediction in my IntellIJ IDE.

I need to create 2 or more structures which will have name the same as their value, but the names can't be the same on that 2 structures. And I need to know that on the TypeScript compiling time.

E.g

I was wondering about using Enums :

```
enum Direction {
    Up = "UP",
    Down = "DOWN",
    Left = "LEFT",
    Right = "RIGHT",
}
```

But I need to somehow prevent of the duplicate of the members name of the all occurences of enums or "another, better solution structure" in that file.

Like :

```
enum Direction {
        Up = "UP",
        Down = "DOWN",
        Left = "LEFT",
        Right = "RIGHT",
}

enum HorizontalDirection {
    Left = "LEFT",
    Right = "RIGHT",
}
```

And after that I want to get an Error that the 'Left' and 'Right' field already exist with keeping separation of that structure. (I can't create one class/ enum with all that fields).

Like extending Enums but not overriding old values but gives an error.

Maybe there is a way to do so ?